# Cannot install jdk 1.5 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, java

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic x86_64). Some info about the machine:

```
$ grep --color "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz
```

I need to install jdk5 to support an old application.

I have tried:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-5-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-5-jdk
```

I have also tried:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install sun-java5-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sun-java5-jdk
```

So its not available in the repos. I have tried to follow this guide (adding the jaunty repos):

http://leonardo-pinho.blogspot.dk/2010/11/java-15-no-ubuntu-1010.html

but same result.

Then I have tried to download jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html#jdk-1.5.0_22-oth-JPR

and do:

```
~$ chmod a+x jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin 
~$ sudo ./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin 
Sun Microsystems, Inc.  Binary Code License Agreement

yes
Unpacking...
Checksumming...
0
0
Extracting...
./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin: 424: ./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin: ./install.sfx.19556: not found
./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin: 1: cd: can't cd to jdk1.5.0_22
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1) You try to install a 32-bit JDK (jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-**i586**.bin) on a 64-bit Linux (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic **x86_64**).

The JDK 1.5.0_22 Java installer (`install.sfx.XXXXX`) needs these libraries to run (from my 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04):

```
$ ldd install.sfx.5362 
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x004df000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0022e000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00b96000)
```

which corresponds to package `libc6-i386`. Install it (`sudo apt-get install libc6-i386`) and try again.

2) Use the 64-bit JDK.

Answer (score 2):

Java 1.5 is so down rev, it is no longer officially supported by Oracle and because of licensing issues that hinder redistribution you cannot install it use **apt-get**

You **can** download an executable that will install Java 1.5 from the oracle.com site.
On Oracle.com follow the Download links for Java Developers and click on Older (or Other) Releases

Then refer to [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Oracle_.28Sun.29_Java_6) which describes how to set up Java 1.6

When setting up the alternatives substitute 1.6 for 1.5

```
sudo update-alternatives --install \
 "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/java" 1

sudo update-alternatives --install \
 "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/javac" 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these packages are not found in Ubuntu 12.04 repositories. However, you can install any of these two packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

To search for open-jdk package, you can use the following command:

```
$ apt-cache search openjdk
```

Comment: I need jdk5 not jdk6 or jdk7